# Swift compatibility between versions for a library

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sdk, frameworks

I'm distributing libraries for other developers to use (http://empiric.al). I've noticed that between swift versions, even 2.0 to 2.1, I'll get `Module file was created by a (newer/older) version of the compiler.`

I need to be distribute in a future-proof way.

How can I make sure my compiled frameworks can be used by newer versions of Swift in the future so I don't have to recompile as soon as Apple puts a new beta out?

Answer (score 11):

From [Apple's website](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=2):

> Binary Compatibility and Frameworks
>
> While your app’s runtime compatibility is ensured, the Swift language
>   itself will continue to evolve, and the binary interface will also
>   change. To be safe, all components of your app should be built with
>   the same version of Xcode and the Swift compiler to ensure that they
>   work together.
>
> This means that frameworks need to be managed carefully. For instance,
>   if your project uses frameworks to share code with an embedded
>   extension, you will want to build the frameworks, app, and extensions
>   together. It would be dangerous to rely upon binary frameworks that
>   use Swift — especially from third parties. As Swift changes, those
>   frameworks will be incompatible with the rest of your app. When the
>   binary interface stabilizes in a year or two, the Swift runtime will
>   become part of the host OS and this limitation will no longer exist.

Answer (score 3):

Until the Swift ABI (application binary interface) stabilises (I'm guessing another year or two) the only way to distribute libraries that will work across different Xcode versions is to distribute the source code. Cocoa pods and Carthage are both good tools for making library distribution easier but for Swift code they will still rely on source code being available.

It might be possible to have an Cocoapod that detects the version of Xcode it is run with and then downloads and provides the correct build of your library but you will still need to build the libraries for all Xcode versions that you want to support and recompile every time Apple release a new Xcode but at least the user wouldn't need to download a new version manually.