# Audio Unit V3 Extensions: Swift vs. Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, audiounit

I want to create an Audio Unit Extension for iOS using the new AU Extentions v3 framework. The documentation and sample code provided by Apple is sparse and only available in Swift format.

Does this mean it's only possible to create AU Extensions using Swift, or is it theoretically also possible using Objective-C? In other words: will I run into something blocking when I attempt to port the sample code into Objective-C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding from the session at WWDC 2015 ([session 508](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/508/?id=508)) was that Objective-C is actually the recommended language for Audio Unit Extensions. This is because the Swift ABI has not yet stabilized, so if you built an extension with one version of Swift, and it is hosted inside an application built with a different Swift version, you'll run into problems.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33353101/swift-compatibility-between-versions-for-a-library) discusses the Swift ABI in more detail.

**Update**: I went back and searched [asciiwwdc.com](http://asciiwwdc.com/2015/sessions/508) to find the comment I was thinking of (this is from session 508 of 2015 WWDC):

> So if you are going to build a framework to be loaded in process on OS X, despite what we are doing here with Swift, we can't recommend that you do this on OS X because the Swift API is subject to change.

(I'm pretty sure he said ABI, but someone transcribed it as API.)