# Binary compatibility of different versions of Swift

Tags: ios, swift

We are developing an iOS framework using Swift 2.2. This framework is intended for outside use, i.e., its built binary will be distributed to our clients, and they will use it to develop their applications.

Another update: Swift 3 will not have ABI compatibility. See here: https://www.infoq.com/news/2016/05/swift-3-no-stable-abi.

So if we author the framework in Swift, and the only way to guarantee our clients using different versions of Swift can consume it safely is to build multiple versions of the framework, and ask them to download the version that matches theirs, right?

Comment: Answers in the linked page are still valid, otherwise you would have seen new answers about the changes, no doubt about that. :)

Answer (score 2):

From Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/).

> Swift 2.3 and Swift 3 are not binary compatible so your app's entire
>   code base needs to pick one version of Swift.

Also [here is a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33353101/swift-compatibility-between-versions-for-a-library) that you may find helpful.

Comment: Also note that ABI compatibility won't be introduced in Swift 3, it has been postponed, see https://www.infoq.com/news/2016/05/swift-3-no-stable-abi