# How can I force Xcode 8.x to embrace particular swift language version?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, compatibility, abi

This is to my requirement where, I would like to **distribute libraries in binary form** so as to protect intellectual property, license agreements etc. So use of Cocoapods, Carthage, SPM is ruled out to solve this.

Since ABI (application binary interface compatibility) is yet to be adapted or even announced by Apple,what is the best way to handle this.

Reading [this](http://www.bensnider.com/abi-compatibility-whoopdty-do-what-does-it-all-mean.html#abi-compatibility-whoopdty-do-what-does-it-all-mean) nice insight about ABI and similar concern, it looks solution is ad-hoc -- to release binary libraries for all coming Xcode where Swift language is upgraded.

While not that similar question is there on stack [Swift compatibility between versions for a library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33353101/swift-compatibility-between-versions-for-a-library)

Answer to [my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41802967/why-i-have-to-release-multiple-version-of-framework-library-sdk-for-each-ios-x) looks to go on with ad-hoc way and wait & watch until Switch 4.0 (may) to come and help.

I tried all other ways suggested on this (toggle SWIFT_VERSION settings and use of .xcconfig to set version ).

Comment: I need to admit that I'm using ad-hoc approach and its working as I code without tail (would have used it to hold mouse)